# How to Install npm without root in Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've installed node into a custom directory in my home folder called local per these instructions : 
https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Result :

```
creating  ./icu_config.gypi
* Using ICU in deps/icu-small
```

Error:

> could not load deps/icu-small/source/common/unicode/uvernum.h

is ICU installed?

Comment: I think this belongs on the [ubuntu stackexchange](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a permissions issue in your home directory. To reclaim ownership of the .npm directory execute:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.npm
```